# Mac OS X: getting names of changed/written files

Tags: logging, macos

I remember having a command line tool on an older Mac OS X version (Tiger?) that told me the name of every file that was written to (or read) by any process on the system. It used fseventd (? or something like that). Is there something like that for the newest Mac OS X (10.6)? It should be run in a terminal window and then I can use the system as normal. Let's say I type `cat /etc/passwd`, the output of that program would be similar to

```
/bin/cat
/etc/passwd
```

I can't use `lsof` because I can't get the timing right.

Is this clear or do you need more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `fs_usage` as root.

Comment: Revisiting the answer for sake of completeness. There is also iosnoop - Quoting the manpage: "snoop I/O events as they occur. Uses DTrace."